# Altium PCB Layout: The Difference of Through Via, Micro Via, and Burried Via

Tags: pcb, altium, layout, via, drill

This is my very first time doing 4 layers PCB layout.

What is actually the difference between Micro Via and Buried Via?
Say I have Layer 1, Layer 2, Layer 3, Layer 4. What I know I use the Through Via for Layer 1 as start layer and Layer 4 for Stop Layer.

And how do I use the Micro Via and Buried Via?

Last question, what about the Drill Pair Properties, should I connect every layer there?

Comment: This question is very similar to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/25429/104097.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blind vias connect an exposed surface with an inner layer, but do not go through the entire board.

Buried vias connect inner layers with each other, and to not extend into the top or bottom layer.

Microvias are drilled with a laser instead of a regular drill bit, usually in a process step before the layers are laminated together.

While there is no technical reason why blind and buries vias couldn't be drilled regularly, their main use case is in BGA breakout, where high density is important, and mechanical drills would be too fragile.

Thus, blind and buried vias are microvias.

A four layer board is constructed by laminating two thinner two layer boards together, and connecting these together. Blind vias can then be placed between layer 1 and 2, and between layer 3 and 4, and do not affect the other half of the board.

Buried vias become possible starting from four layers on -- 1-2, 1-2-3, 4-5-6 and 5-6 are possible options for blind vias, and 2-3 is a possible option for a buried via.

Using microvias and restricting the layers touched by the via mainly defines which drill file the coordinates go into, and which layers get a copper blob around these coordinates. It is perfectly possible to use a microvia through all layers as well.

Drill pair properties define which layers are manufactured together. Usually, 1-2, 3-4, 5-6 etc. go together, unless you have a strange stackup. In general, try to make microvias only between drill pairs, as manufacturing can become more expensive if there are additional drilling and plating steps even for the in-between substrate (here, normal vias should probably work fine.

Comment: might I suggest adding this image for easier understanding? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/Via_Types.svg/220px-Via_Types.svg.png

Comment: Blind and buried vias are NOT always laser-drilled microvias - they're also achievable just by drilling and plating the layers before bonding. 

The main reason to avoid blind/buried vias is the manufacturing cost, as they add extra steps. Any physical defects in buried vias are also hidden, so electrical testing is key.

Answer (score 2):

One thing about microvias is that each via connect two adjacent layers, only. The laser cannot punch through more than two layers. To connect layers that are not adjacent or several layers you need to setup staggered or stacked microvias.
Stacked are just that: stacked on top each other. Staggered are placed next to each other but not on the same layer.
[image: picture of stacked and staggered microvias]

Answer (score 0):

If you route a 4 layer PCB with 2 layers for signals and two layers for GND and VCC, you will not need buried vias when the two signal layers are top and bottom layer and the power layers are between them. Ask your manufacturer about the cost of normal vias and blind, buried and micro vias.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Lars's comment. Some manufacturers will support the use of "skip" and "core" vias. This is a type of via of which the hole is filled with copper or epoxy, which connect tracks on 2 different layers that don't have to be adjacent or close to each other.