# Multi-layer board drill pair recommendations to reduce PCB cost

Tags: altium, pcb-layers, via, multi-layer, drill

I'm designing a simple 6 layer board with following as core components.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c123gh6pm.pdf
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/afe4403.pdf

I using this stackup 
[image]

Now I'm looking at the drill pairs so that will give optimal performance by not bumping the cost. I heard that buried via will incur more costs compared to blind or thru hole via.

Please recommend some multilayered board drill pair for simple typical 6 layer board.

Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: drill pair recommendations to reduce PCB cost?

Comment: Talk to your board house.  The answer depends on their exact process.

Comment: Yes I did talk to them what they suggested is to use thru hole or buried vias instead of micro and blind.

Comment: But my question is what are the commonly used drill pairs defined for such typical 6 layer boards.

Comment: So long as you use thru vias, this has nothing to do with cost, which makes it hard to respond to your premise.

Comment: Lets say If I use 3 drill pairs (Top-Bot, Top-Sig1, Sig2-Bot), then extending/ending the VIAs with nets (ex, Power or clock signals) to  Top/Bot/GND/VCC/Sig1/Sig2 layers regardless where they start and end, will be a good practice?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25429/blind-buried-vs-through-hole-vias?rq=1

Comment: @12Lapointep Thank you very much. Think the link you shared has more or less answered my question. I will need to check couple of things regarding 0.5mm BGA before making my mind.

Comment: Guys, thanks for all the help could you please tell me how to mark this question as answered?